# jQuery/Ajax Mobile Page Transitions Not Working with Bootstrap RC1

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with the new bootstrap and jQuery. I'm trying to figure out the best way to navigate between pages with gestures.

I originally had `location.replace` fire after registering a gesture. Then I found the Ajax method [here](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/pages/), which has divs and links between the divs as if they're pages:

`<div data-role="page" id="foo">`

However when I run this with Bootstrap, the buttons click fine, but load a blank page, even though the URL reflects the proper domain at `mydomain.com/page#foo`. If I reload, it loads the 'second page'.

I know I could do this different ways, but is a) am I doing the best way with ajax linking, and b) why isn't it working? Should I just go with method one and add transitions to the page loads?

Background on the app is a completely mobile web app.

```
<head>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<!-- Navbar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Meteor Prototype</a>
    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="map-page.php">Map Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="exhibit-list-page.php">Exhibit List Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="exhibit-page.php">Exhibit Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="top-level-museum.php">Top Level Museum</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">

<!-- Start of first page -->
<div data-role="page" id="foo">

<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Foo</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">
    <p>I'm first in the source order so I'm shown as the page.</p>
    <p>View internal page called <a href="#bar">bar</a></p>
</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
<!-- Start of second page -->
<div data-role="page" id="bar">

<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Bar</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">
    <p>I'm the second in the source order so I'm hidden when the page loads. I'm just shown if a link that references my id is beeing clicked.</p>
    <p><a data-transition="flip" data-inline="true" href="#foo">Back to foo</a></p>
</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

   <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>
```

Comment: show us your HTML. And are these pages multiple pages?

Comment: I'm fine with either 1 page as the code is above, or separate pages. Ultimately I'm using swipe gestures to load different pages. That works fine with jQuery Mobile, but again, I can't attach a transition.

Comment: where's the code that changes pages?

Comment: @koala_dev Default implementation of [jquery mobile](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/#Settingatransition)

Comment: @ElijahMurray you seem to be jQuery Mobile CSS, and also, you need to add the jQuery.js and jQM.js in `head`.

Comment: @hungerpain I have jquery and JQM in the footer, though not sure what you mean by "you seem to be jQuery Mobile CSS"...jQM doesn't have CSS as far as I understand? It does have implementation to internally link to anchor texts and perform a page transition using the `data-transition` property, but it isn't working when I combine it with Bootstrap.

Comment: You do need jQM CSS, either one with a theme, or the structure only. Also try moving your js files to the head

Comment: @koala_dev It was jQM CSS! Don't know how I missed that it existed. Any idea how to integrate the transitions and bind them to my swipe event listener?

`$( document ).on( "swipeleft", swipeleftHandler );`

Comment: check out the [changePage()](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/) method